# Display optional text in Exit Dialog upon ininstall

Tags: wix, windows-installer

I understand that the built-in Exit Dialog will display after the installer completes successfully (whether it is an install/modify/repair or remove). I want to be able to customize the message displayed in the Exit Dialog for uninstallation. I figured I could use the built-in textbox (WIXUI_EXITDIALOGOPTIONALTEXT) to display my 'install completed successfully' message.

I use a custom action in Product.wxs file.

```
<CustomAction Id="SetExitDialogOptText" Property="WIXUI_EXITDIALOGOPTIONALTEXT" Value="Thank you for Uninstalling [ProductName]."></CustomAction>

<InstallUISequence>
<Custom Action="SetExitDialogOptText" Before="ExecuteAction">
<![CDATA[REMOVE~="ALL"]]>
</Custom>
</InstallUISequence>
```

Unfortunately, this would not work. REMOVE~="ALL" is supposed be the condition for removal (uninstall). Am I missing something here?

As a side note, the custom action works and displays the message in the 'optional text box' is I set the condition to 'NOT Installed'. But of course this would display the 'uninstall succesfull' message after an installation, which is not what I want.

I would appreciate any help with this matter.Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The WixUI ExitDialog does not support showing text during uninstall. You'd have to use a customized version of ExitDialog to get that behavior. See [Changing the UI sequence of a built-in dialog set](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/wixui/wixui_customizations.html) for details.